# Running helm upgrade not updating user pods - Jupyterhub

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub, helm3

As title states, running helm upgrade is not updating my user pods.  Currently have culling and scheduling disabled (via the Helm chart)...but I believed that wouldn't/shouldn't matter.  Is there another option I'm missing or misunderstanding?

JupyterHub chart version `0.11.1`

More information, I can tell the hub, proxy, and other deployments update when running helm upgrade, why wouldn't the user pods as well?

Update: This is necessary when the docker image the user pods are relying on is updated with anything.

Comment: we need more information. In a nutshell, if the pod spec does not change, the pod wont be updated/restart as there is nothing to update.

Comment: Also in my experience the pods aren’t restarted automatically with a helm apply. You need to restart the pods manually or wait for users to do so or for them to be culled. We’ve always found this to be a nice property (can update without disrupting user sessions)

Comment: If the image the pod uses changes @TheFool ?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado sounds like culling to force user pods to retrieve new updates?  Would be nice if there is a way to indicate the user pod needs to restart.  Very surprising this isn't part of the workflow.

Comment: @MarkII, if the image changes, pods are restarted. Anything that changes the pod spec causes a restart. Some people use annotation with revision or timestamp to cause a restart even though the image tag didnt change, for example. Helm upgrade has also a --force flag which forces recreation of *all* resources.

Comment: its the same as when you would run kubectl apply. Kubernetes will determine what needs to be restarted / recreated based on the current state of the cluster and your things you want to apply.